# Cake PHP Error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on Model

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I building my first cake PHP application, all things configured correctly, but when i calling to model on controller as below it gives an error message when i browse this url on localhost

```
class NotesController extends AppController{
var $name = "Notes";

function index(){
    $this->set('notes',$this->Note->find('all'));
}
}
```

**this gives an error like this.**
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in D:\wamp\www\cakephp\app\Model\note.php on line 4

my model file has follow codes

```
class Note extends AppModel{
  $name = "Note";
}
```

i think db connection and other configurations are ok,please any one can help me, i ll highly appreciated you. thanks lot....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$name = "Note";
```

To:

```
var $name = "Note";
```

or:

```
public $name = "Note";
```

CakePHP recommends using `var` to keep code compatible with PHP4. However, this is completely unnecessary and it's better to use `public`.

That being said, the code you posted should not give an `unexpected T_STRING` error but, rather, an `unexpected T_VARIABLE` error. So there may be something else going on as well.

Comment: great thanks for help, i using 5.3.8 so i use variable name with public..thanks again

Comment: if you are using cake2, throw it away completely. totally unnecessary (only needed in cake1.x for PHP4).

Comment: Mark, why would you remove the visibility scope from php5 code...?

Comment: He means to throw away the use of `var` and to just use the PHP5 access modifiers instead.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
var $name = "Note";
```

but that's php4, you want php5+

```
public $name = "Note";
```

when there are errors like this I suggest you to google them first. They're really easy to find and resolve. Also you might want to read about OOP first because it does not look like you have experience with it -> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: great thanks for help, i using 5.3.8 so i use variable name with public..thanks again